# Sort Words in a Dictionary by The Amount Of Times They Appear

Tags: python, dictionary

String = "Today was a very a good day. Tomorrow might be a better day"
I want to sort the each word in a dictionary by the amount of time they have appeared. So the output will be:

```
 {3: ['a'], 2: ['day'], 1: ['Today', 'was', 'very', 'good', 'Tomorrow', 'might', 'be', 
 'better']}
```

I am really unsure about how to approach this problem. The code I have so far:

```
String = "Today was a very a good day. Tomorrow might be a better day"
word = String.split()
frequency = {}
count = 0

for i in word:
    count = +1
```

Answer (score 3):

The [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) has `defaultdict` and `Counter`, made specifically for problems like this -

1. `Counter` let's you fetch a count for each time a token uniquely occurred in the data.
2. `Defaultdict` let's you create a dictionary with lists as values where you can restructure (and remove duplicates) the output of the `Counter` in the form you need.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

String = "Today was a very a good day. Tomorrow might be a better day"
tokens = String.replace('.','').split()  #remove the fullstop

d = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in Counter(tokens).items():
    if k not in d[v]:  #if condition to ensure only unique tokens added
        d[v].append(k)
    
output = dict(d)
print(output)
```

```
{1: ['Today', 'was', 'very', 'good', 'Tomorrow', 'might', 'be', 'better'],
 3: ['a'],
 2: ['day']}
```

---

You can also get the unique tokens and their counts using [numpy.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) instead of `collections.Counter`, but that would be a roundabout way of doing this.

```
np.unique(tokens, return_counts=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Akshay answear, putting in ascending order:

```py
output = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[0],reverse=False))
```

Output:

```
{
1: ['Today', 'was', 'very', 'good', 'Tomorrow', 'might', 'be', 'better'], 
2: ['day'], 
3: ['a']
}
```

If you want descending order, just `reverse=True`. And here it is how you order by `word : count`

```py
String = "Today was a very a good day. Tomorrow might be a better day"
word = String.split()
frequency = {}
count = 0

for i in word:
    if i not in frequency:
        frequency[i] = 1
    else:
        frequency[i] += 1

frequency = dict(sorted(frequency.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
{
'a': 3, 
'Today': 1, 
'was': 1, 
'very': 1, 
'good': 1, 
'day.': 1, 
'Tomorrow': 1, 
'might': 1, 
'be': 1, 
'better': 1, 
'day': 1
}
```